# outlier detection for sparse data in categorical variable

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, sparse

I have a big dataset with a column "clientid" and a categorical column "choice".
I want to find out what are the clients that have strange combinations of choices (less frequent ones) and being able in the future to identify them immediately.

| clientid | choice |
| --- | --- |
| cl1 | a |
| cl2 | b |
| cl2 | c |
| cl3 | d |
| cl4 | b |
| cl4 | c |

If I transpose the table by clientID I have a row for each client and different columns based on the choices, it will became a sparse dataset with categorical variables (choices). Some clients have only one choice and some have multiple ones and I want to find outlier records (clientid)

Which type of algorithm could help me in this type of problem?
It is unsupervised, so I dont know what are the normal combinations and it is sparse data on categorical variables.